# How to use ggplot2 and facet_wrap but do not drop factors within a group on x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I want to use facet_wrap to plot different values on the x axis for different groups. However, when using `scale = "free_x"`, it shows unique values within each group. See example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
nb = rep(LETTERS[1:3],4)
expand.grid(LETTERS[1:3], 1:3)
df = data.frame(ps = paste(rep(c("ps1","gc1"),6)),
                cr = rep(LETTERS[1:3],4),
                id = rep(x = month.abb[1:4], each = 3));df
df = df[order(df$ps),]
df[df$ps == "ps1","cr"] <- sample(LETTERS[4:6], size = 6, replace = TRUE)
df.all = rbind(df,df,df,df,df,df)
df.all$val = rnorm(n = nrow(df.all))

ggplot(df.all, 
       aes(x = cr,
           y = val)) + 
  geom_violin() +
  facet_wrap(vars(ps, id), 
             scales = "free_x",
             ncol = 4) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1), 
             alpha= .3)
```

In the image here (which is the output of the code above), I added the missing levels. Basically, there is the group "gc1" where I'd like the levels not to be dropped. But I also don't want the levels from the "ps1" to be appearing in the "gc1". So in the end gc1 should only show levels A, B, C and ps1 should only show D, E, and F. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by using the `ggh4x` package which via `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` allows to set the scales for each facet individually, e.g. for your case your could do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(
  df.all,
  aes(
    x = cr,
    y = val
  )
) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1),
    alpha = .3
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(ps, id),
    scales = "free_x",
    ncol = 4
  ) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(
      ps == "gc1" ~ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("A", "B", "C")),
      ps == "ps1" ~ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("D", "E", "F"))
    )
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** Here is one approach to create the scales dynamically from the data which loops over the `ps` groups and uses `reformulate` to  create the `formula`s for `facetted_pos_scales`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

scale_x <- lapply(unique(df.all$ps), \(x) {
  reformulate(
    paste0("scale_x_discrete(limits=sort(unique(df.all$cr[df.all$ps =='", x, "'])))"),
    paste0("ps == '", x, "'")
  )  
})

ggplot(
  df.all,
  aes(
    x = cr,
    y = val
  )
) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1),
    alpha = .3
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(ps, id),
    scales = "free_x",
    ncol = 4
  ) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = scale_x
  )
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the `scale_x_discrete(limits =` automatically? I basically have this same type of data, but >100 groups and would not want to do it all by hand!

Comment: Sure. See my edit for an approach to dynamically create the list of scales.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), times = 6)) %>%
  mutate(val = rnorm(n = n())) %>% 
  bind_rows(crossing(ps = "gc1", 
                     cr = LETTERS[1:3], 
                     id = unique(df.all$id)) %>%
              mutate(val = NA_real_),
            crossing(ps = "ps1", 
                     cr = LETTERS[4:6], 
                     id = unique(df.all$id)) %>%
              mutate(val = NA_real_)
            ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cr, y = val)) + 
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1), alpha = .3) +
  facet_wrap(~ ps + id, scales = "free_x", ncol = 4)
```

[image]